# closing a pop-up when clicking elsewhere windows phone 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, windows-phone-7, popup

I'm trying to close the pop-up I opened with clicking elsewhere.

I tried to use Mouse_LeftButtonDown event on the Content Panel and App Page, but when I click  "button" to open the popup, the event closes it so I cannot even see pop-up. What should I do with this matter?

(I'm using User-control class pop-up)

```
private void ContentPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
if(popup.IsOpen==true)
    popup.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could deal with UserControl_LostFocus event

```
 private void UserControl_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Popup test = this.Parent as Popup;
        test.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

Comment: at first didn't work , but it worked when the pop-up opens I used 'userControl.Focus();' thanks!